# Google smart home command for blinds

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I would like to control blinds using google smart home action. How can I create commands like "turn/put my blind up/down" ? What device traits should I use? It seems OnOff trait doesn't understand up and down, can I custom it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **undocumented (use at your own risk)** device type: `action.devices.types.BLINDS`.

Instead you could use for traits:

- [On/Off](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/onoff): `action.devices.traits.OnOff`
- [Brightness](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/brightness): `action.devices.traits.Brightness`

In this way, you can ask Google to **set** a specific position, to **close** (in Italian *it works as a turn off command*, in English, I did not try yet), to **turn on** or to **turn off**. The open command instead seems to be not recognized as a turn on command.

Hope to help you and hope that Google releases soon types and traits for blinds/curtain control.

**EDIT** as pointed out by @robin-thoni is not documented: https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/guides/blinds

Comment: Thanks, yes, it works like open and close. but it doestn't understand "put blind up/down".

Comment: You can control them like a dimmer light, see [the official Google Home help](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7073578?hl=en-GB) for further commands

Comment: @pincopallino How did you find out about undocumented devices like this ?

Comment: On a [french forum](https://www.jeedom.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38423&start=160) looking on Google for blinds control

Comment: It is now documented: https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/guides/blinds